# How can I create a python function that will clear all the messages in a channel on Discord?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to write a python function that I can call based on a conditional statement that would completely get rid of all the messages in a channel while keeping the channel intact.

I've used the discord.py library but can't get my head around the async functions and so.

Is there a more efficient way to do this or could I be point in the right direction?

I'm trying to write something like clear_channel(channel_id), that would be a one_liner to be called when the channel needs to be wiped.

Thank you :)

Tried using async functions and got stuck

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A basic example, should accomplish what you are after.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.command()
async def clear(ctx, limit: int = 100):
    """Clears the specified number of messages. Default is 100."""
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit + 1)  # +1 to also remove the command message itself
```

I would take a look at the python docs to understand async functions and the event loop. [Event Loop Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.tree.command(name="clear")
async def clear(interaction:discord.Interaction, limit:int=None):
    if limit is not None:
        await interaction.channel.purge(limit=limit)
    if limit is None:
        await interaction.channel.purge()
```

While this code is with slash commands if you want it with normal commands cause you don't know how to set up slash commands then here it is:

```
@bot.command()
async def clear(ctx:commands.Context, limit:int=None):
    if limit is not None:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit)
    if limit is None:
        await ctx.channel.purge()
```

Comment: How could I then execute this on discord, would it be !clear, assuming the bot has all the relevant permissions

Comment: For the first one you need to sync the tree commands in your `on_ready()` event with `await bot.tree.sync()` and then you can type / into discord and it will give you the option. 
For the second one it is !clear